# Porque a api key ( google ) não funciona ao adicionar restrição de chave

Tags: android, android-studio, api, api-key

Tenho 2 api key, uma com restrição para apps android e outra sem, quando coloco o app para usar a api com restrição ele não consegue acessar a api retornando o Erro "403 Forbidden", na api sem restrições tudo funciona normalmente.

Já conferir a SHA-1 e o pacote e tudo parece esta correto.
[image: api com restrição]

Comment: Você gerou sha-1 como release?

Comment: eu fiz usando este tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode

Comment: Se você gerou sha-1 debug, então isso ai deve funcionar, basta colocar a chave gerada no seu projeto.

Comment: No projeto que você diz, no android studio ou na restrição da api no console do google? se for no android aonde eu coloco ?

Comment: Veja essa imagem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Ppn.png Na terceira tela tem o google_maps_api.xml. No lugar de YOUR_KEY_HERE. você deve colocar a chave que gerou no no console do google.

Comment: Eu já fiz isso, porem da erro quando eu acesso usando a key q tem restrição, esse é o problema =/

Comment: Não estou entendendo. Que restrição é essa?! Onde?! No aplicativo?! Cê já deu acesso a internet no Manifest?!

Comment: Olha na imagem que tem no post, tenho uma key com a opção "nenhum" e essa com a restrição de chave para "apps android", a chave coma restrição não funciona, e a sem restrição funciona

Comment: Isso aí é o seguinte, você pode restringir essa chave somente para Android  para funcionar somente no seu app. Caso deixe liberado, vai funcionar tanto na web quanto android, ou ios etc, mas você corre o risco de alguém tentar usar seu chave em outro website, caso consiga roubar essa chave. Isso faz com que, caso você tema muito acesso, exceda sua cota gratuita de acesso ao google maps api. =D

Comment: Provavelmente não está funcionando no seu app, porque você errou em algum dos seus procedimentos em relação ao tutorial, ou o mesmo pode não está totalmente correto por haver alguma atualização. Porque também essa resposta ai é de 2015.

Comment: Tenho o mesmo problema: Ao cadastrar a restrição de chave para ***apps para android***, meu app não consegue mais acesso. Tenho certeza sobre o nome do pacote e também da SHA1, pois utilizo no firebase.